# Will some of my photos and files still remain in the memory if I do a factory reset?

Tags: data-recovery, encryption, files

Just wondering... If I sell my Android phone, is it possible for the new owner to use some data recovery software and recover some of the files?

Comment: No. except you have pre Lollipop device or manually disabled encryption